# How can I restrict the specific year in date picker in iPhone programatically?

Tags: ios, date, uidatepicker

How can I restrict the specific year in a date picker in iPhone programatically?

For example, if user's date of birth is 1990 then I need to restrict the user to select the previous years from 1990 (1989, 1988, *etc.*). How can I restrict those years in the date picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use: `[picker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];`
In place of [NSDate date] set your requirement according to you.